# ngChange-like functionality for the entire form

Tags: angularjs, onchange, forms

I would like to do an equivalent of `ng-change` for the entire form whenever there is a change in one of its input fields.

I know that since AngularJS 1.3 I have the debounce option but it applies only for a single input.

I'm looking for a "debounce"/"on change" functionality that will apply for the entire form.

Comment: I believe your best bet is to make a directive for all your inputs (that you want debounce on) and set the debounce setting there, but let it pass the ng-model and other stuff from your inputs.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There isn't a built-in way to do `ng-change` for a form.

It may not even be needed, because if you organized your view model properly, then your form inputs are likely bound to a certain scope-exposed property:

```
$scope.formData = {};
```

and in the View:

```
<form name="form1">
  <input ng-model="formData.a">
  <input ng-model="formData.b">
</form>
```

Then you could deep-watch (with `$watch`) for model changes (and apply whatever debounce option on elements that you need):

```
$scope.$watch("formData", function(){
  console.log("something has changed");
}, true);
```

**Then problem is**, of course, that this is a deep-watch and it is expensive. Also, it reacts not only to changes in the Form, but also to a change in `formData` from any source.

So, as an alternative, you could create your own directive to compliment the form and react to form's change events.

```
.directive("formOnChange", function($parse){
  return {
    require: "form",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
       var cb = $parse(attrs.formOnChange);
       element.on("change", function(){
          cb(scope);
       });
    }
  }
});
```

and the usage is:

```
<form name="form1" form-on-change="doSomething()">
  <input ng-model="formData.a">
  <input ng-model="formData.b">
</form>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/el1Z5z37geFsAc76toFv?p=preview) for illustration.

Note, that the "change" event is fired only on blur for a text input, as per [jQuery documentation:](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

> The `change` event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to `<input>` elements, `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>` elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.

Comment: You can also detect text input changes by also listening for keyboard events in that directive, add:`element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
        cb(scope);
      });`

Comment: Is it also possible to exclude some types (input, select, button ect.)? I added the click event and I'm trying to exclude the button type. I can see the button logged with console.log(attrs);

Comment: It seems that this won't work if using the angular built in jqlite variant of jQuery.

Answer (score 10):

one "hacky" way to do this is by setting a watcher to the form dirty, valid depending on your requirements you can do something like

```
   $scope.$watch('form.$dirty',function(v){
         if(!v){return}
         form.$setPristine()
         /*do something here*/
    })
```

this will execute everytime the form gets modified, if you only want to execute your code on valid modified form you can do

```
       if(!v || form.$invalid){return}
```

and if you only want to execute your code when the form steps to $valid state just need to set up your watcher for 'form.$valid'

if you don't like to pollute your scope with watchers, you can always create a directive around the form  that exposes a on-change api event and internally takes care of the watcher

Answer (score 8):

As per Eric Soyke comment you could hook up the check of the form change on the keyup event.

This way you could simply use the builtin directive ng-keyup:

```
<form name="form1" ng-keyup="doSomething()">
```

Comment: +1
This is the answer I needed since New Dev's solution was only working if the focus is lost (as he already mentioned) which does not give the user experience I wanted. Ty both though :)

Comment: Wouldn't work with autofill plugins (unless they fire keyup event).

Answer (score 2):

okay, super super late answer ... but this works pretty neat

```
// html
<form name="$ctrl.form">...</form>

// controller
function $postLink() {
    ctrl.form.$$element.on('change', function () {
        console.log('fired');
    });
}
```

Comment: This is effectively the second part of the accepted answer.

Comment: `$$` indicates a private property. You should avoid using this.