# Watch form model for changes

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-watch

Assuming a given form such as `<form name="myForm">`, it's easy enough to watch for validity, error, dirty state, etc. using a simple watch:

```
$scope.$watch('myForm.$valid', function() {
  console.log('form is valid? ', $scope.myForm.$valid); 
});
```

However, there doesn't appear to be an easy way to watch if any given input in this form has changed. Deep watching like so, does not work:

```
$scope.$watch('myForm', function() {
  console.log('an input has changed'); //this will never fire
}, true);
```

`$watchCollection` only goes one level deep, which means I would have to create a new watch for every input. Not ideal.

What is an elegant way to watch a form for changes on any input without having to resort to multiple watches, or placing `ng-change` on each input?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS 1.3 - \`ng-change\`-like functionality for the entire form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677638/angularjs-1-3-ng-change-like-functionality-for-the-entire-form)

Comment: The directive solution in that question works, but it's not what I had in mind (i.e. not elegant, since it requires blur in order to work). Ideally I would like this to work in a similar way that angular internally sets a form to $valid or $error immediately after a child input changes appropriately.

Answer (score 7):

Concerning the [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677638/angularjs-1-3-ng-change-like-functionality-for-the-entire-form) and your comment:

> The directive solution in that question works, but it's not what I had in mind (i.e. not elegant, since it requires blur in order to work).

It works if you add `true` as third parameter for your `$watch`:

```
$scope.$watch('myFormdata', function() {
    console.log('form model has been changed');
}, true);
```

Further information see the [docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch).

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0d9hfp28/2/) (check console log)

---

Another *more angular way* would be to use angular's `$pristine`. This boolean property will be set to `false` once you manipulate the form model:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0d9hfp28/1/)

Comment: Indeed I'm aware that it works that way assuming your form fields all share a common parent object. And I can use a watch in that way - I was ideally hoping there would be a way to watch using the form name, rather than the model each input is bound to

Comment: It depends if you need the new value. If you just want to now that something has changed you sould be using `$pristine`.

Comment: It's in the context of an autosave, so while ```$pristine``` or ```$dirty``` would be useful for the first change, they are not useful for every subsequent change unless I were to manually set the pristine/dirty value on every save which seems a bit hacky to me. I'll probably have to settle for a deep watch on the model the inputs share.

Answer (score 4):

Based on my experience with my forms (new dev, but working with Angular for a while now), the elegant way to watch a form for changes is actually not to use any type of watch statement at all actually.
Use the built-in Angular boolean $pristine or $dirty and those values will change automatically on any input field or checkbox.
The catch is: it will not change the value if you add or splice from an array which had me stumped for a while.
The best fix for me was to manually do `$scope.MyForm.$setDirty();` whenever I was adding or removing from my different arrays. 
Worked like a charm!