# Angular ngBlur on multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently trying to "save" all the content in a webpage after a piece is edited. IE, a user clicks into an input, enters some data, and as soon as he/she clicks elsewhere I want to run a function to gather all the model data and save it in browser local storage.

```
<input ng-blur="functionName()" />
```

That's the normal way of doing it, but let's say i have tons of inputs:

```
<input ng-blur="functionName()" />
<input ng-blur="functionName()" />
<input ng-blur="functionName()" />
<input ng-blur="functionName()" />
```

is there anything I can do to apply the `ng-blur` effect to all `inputs` of a page or must I put `ng-blur` attribute into every `input`?

Comment: Use ng-model on each and assign their values to an object and set a watch on the object in your controller.

Comment: @JohnHalbert actually I have most inputs as `<input ng-model="vm.item.type">`. So I can watch this model change from the controller?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom directive to do that. This is an adaptation from this question's answer:

[AngularJS 1.3 - `ng-change`-like functionality for the entire form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677638/angularjs-1-3-ng-change-like-functionality-for-the-entire-form)

Haven't tested this, but it should get you on the right track.

```
.directive('inputsOnBlur', ['$parse', function($parse){
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
       var cb = $parse(attrs.inputsOnBlur);
       element.find('input').on('blur', function(){
          cb(scope);
       });
    }
  }
}]);
```

and to use it:

```
<form inputs-on-blur="doSomething()">
   <input />
   <input />
   <input />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback! Will this also work by putting `inputs-on-blur` in a regular `div` that's a container for all inputs? As I'm not using a form, just the input tag.

Comment: Great, I'll try it out soon. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

of course it's possible.
You need to dynamically add `data-ng-blur` to input tag.
The code in your controller should be :

`var inputList = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('input'));
    inputList.forEach(function (input) {
        input.setAttribute('data-ng-blur', 'functionName()');
        $compile(angular.element(input))($scope);
    });`

Comment: So this basically just programmatically puts `ng-blur` into all the `inputs` for me, right?

Comment: Yes, it will apply `data-ng-blur` to all the inputs in your page. If you want to specify which kind of input should `ng-blur` attach to, you can use `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"')` instead.