# Show Save Button when form has been touched/modify - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have 4 angular forms, and a save button

**save button**

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right admin-hide mb10" ng-show="showSaveBtn == true" ng-click="checkSaveBtn()">Save</button>
</div>
```

**4 forms**

```
{{-- WiFi Includes --}}
@if($section == "private")
    <div ng-form="private2" name="p24Form" ng-show="freqSelect == '2.4'" novalidate>
        @include('views.settings.wifi.private2')
    </div>
    <div ng-form="private5" name="p50Form" ng-show="freqSelect == '5'" novalidate>
        @include('views.settings.wifi.private5')
    </div>
@elseif($section == "guest")
    <div ng-form="guest2" name="g24Form" ng-show="freqSelect == '2.4'" novalidate>
        @include('views.settings.wifi.guest2')
    </div>
    <div ng-form="guest5" name="g50Form" ng-show="freqSelect == '5'" novalidate>
        @include('views.settings.wifi.guest5')
    </div>
@endif
```

I am trying to detect and show my save button as soon as one of those 4 forms got changed.

I've tried

```
$scope.showSaveBtn = false;
$scope.checkSaveBtn = function() {

    if (

        $scope.p24Form.$dirty ||
        $scope.g24Form.$dirty ||
        $scope.p50Form.$dirty ||
        $scope.g50Form.$dirty

        ) {

        $scope.showSaveBtn = true;
    }else{
        $scope.showSaveBtn = false;
    }
}


console.info('$scope.showSaveBtn = ', $scope.showSaveBtn);
```

## Result

`$scope.showSaveBtn` kept returning false ...

Why does it keep returning false ? What did I do wrong ?

How would one go about and debug this further?

---

## Note

[ngChange-like functionality for the entire form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677638/ngchange-like-functionality-for-the-entire-form)

is not answering my post. According to the link, people using  tag, but in my case I used  tag with `ng-form` attribute, the way we use to check it might be slightly different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ngChange-like functionality for the entire form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677638/ngchange-like-functionality-for-the-entire-form)

Comment: I'm not sure that `checkSaveBtn` is meant to be bound to the ng-click event. Shouldn't it be set on `ng-change` of the inputs ?

Comment: @Saksham : According to your link, people using `<form>` tag, but in my case I used `<div>` tag with `ng-form` attribute, the way we check it might be slightly different.

Comment: @JulienTASSIN : Okay, I will try `ng-change` and will update you the result.

Comment: @JulienTASSIN : Result when I used `ng-change` - I got -  `Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'ngChange', can't be found!`

Comment: oups sorry, I didn't see that you don't have ng-model.

Comment: Your ng-change function is never called. This is because you set the ng-click to handle the changes. You have to call that function somewhere such as in a $scope.$watch or somewhere on the form.

Comment: You could possibly try something like this...

`$scope.$watch('[p24Form.$dirty,g24Form.$dirty,p50Form.$dirty,g50Form.$dirty]', function () {
 $scope.checkSaveBtn();
}, true);`